# MS SQL is this possible to do in a view?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, view, database-table

I have 4 tables:
table A:

```
|LineID|
```

table B:

```
|Date|ShiftID|IsWorking|
```

Table C:

```
|LineID|Date|ShiftID|IsWorking|
```

Table D:

```
|ShiftID|HowLongWorks|
```

I need to create a view where I will have

```
|LineID|Date|HowLongWorks|
```

In this view I need to have:
 - all lines from table A
 - All dates from table B for each line
 - sum(HowLongWorks) for all shifts signed to that date where IsWorking = 1

And when LineID, Date, ShiftID combination exists in table C, IsWorking must be taken from table C, if not exists from table B.

Is it possible to do in a view?

For example:
table A:

```
|Line 1|
|Line 2|
```

table B:

```
|2013-01-01|1|1|
|2013-01-01|2|1|
|2013-01-02|1|1|
|2013-01-02|2|0|
|2013-01-03|1|0|
|2013-01-03|2|0|
```

table C:

```
|Line 1|2013-01-01|1|0|
|Line 1|2013-01-01|2|0|
|Line 1|2013-01-02|1|1|
|Line 2|2013-01-03|2|1|
```

table D:

```
|1|8|
|2|10|
```

the result in view should be:

```
|Line 1|2013-01-01|0|
|Line 1|2013-01-02|8|
|Line 1|2013-01-03|0|
|Line 2|2013-01-01|18|
|Line 2|2013-01-02|8|
|Line 2|2013-01-03|10|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
    a.LineID, b.Date,
    sum(case when isnull(c.IsWorking, b.IsWorking) = 1 then d.HowLongWorks else 0 end) as HowLongWorks
from TableA as a
    cross join TableB as b
    left outer join TableC as c on
        c.LineID = a.LineID and c.Date = b.Date and c.ShiftID = b.ShiftID 
    left outer join TableD as d on d.ShiftID = b.ShiftID
group by a.LineID, b.Date
order by LineID, Date
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3187e/5)</kbd>**